# GeoWebCache pre-seed aerial imagery via WMTS as geo-referenced raster e.g. GeoTIFF/GeoJPEG2000

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, geowebcache, wmts

I have a large cache of JPEG files (700,000 tiles) that I've pre-seeded using a standalone GeoWebCache connected to a backing WMTS service.

I'd like to build a visual database with Terra Vista and it does not support OCG service endpoints, e.g. WMTS;  It does however support GeoTIFF.

Before I extend the pre-seed function that GeoWebCache provides:

> Are there any existing tools or methods that will help me convert each JPEG in GeoWebCache's layered EPSG 4326 file cache into a geo-referenced raster format like GeoTIFF?